# Can't download file using helm-find-files?

Tags: helm

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1
I want to download file from *http://whatever.com/file.pdf*

So I use command `helm-find-files` (C-x C-f)

Whe I try `C-x C-f http://whatever.com/file.pdf` , press **return** , as result Emacs open my browser (Chrome) and Chrome download pdf file.
But I want to download file by Emacs.

Comment: Enabling `(url-handler-mode 1)` enables Emacs to do this in general. Does that work with helm?

Comment: Not help. Same result. And show new message: "ad-handle-definition: ‘url-cache-extract’ got redefined"